# Customer Demographic Data

Tags: sentiment-analysis

I am looking for two types of data

1. Demographic data 
   Is there a vendor or data source that could provide demographic information of customers who buy a product? It doesn't include personal information but might have information like which zipcode the customer live, age etc..
2. Sentiment data
   In addition to social media and e-commerce, are there any vendors sell sentiment data for products, brand etc.?

Comment: Yes, they are called data brokers. Warning: using variables such as zip code and age make it *very* easy to discriminate against certain customers. Protect yourself and your company, and stop perpetuating social inequities, by taking the right steps to mitigate the chance of discrimination through algorithms. I recommend [Cathy O'Neil's best seller](https://weaponsofmathdestructionbook.com/) as an easy intro to these serious issues.

Comment: What are the data vendors you could recommender?